# Could Alice's hair send people to sleep without just knocking them out?

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, poisons, sleep, mutation

So recently I asked [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/89462/how-would-having-toxic-hairs-affect-the-everyday-work-life-of-a-human) about Alice, the tips of whose hairs (body and head hairs) could (in that question, not this question) paralyze or poison people.

I thought: what if her hairs only made people sleep? They would contain melatonin or something in large quantities which would trick the human body into thinking it needed to sleep.

Then I started to question whether or not this would be possible. Could Alice send people to sleep - as in, the restorative slumber, complete with potential dreams - or would she be forced to knock them out with a weak toxin to stun them in a way which at all resembles sleep?

Update: Most people seem to be saying no to melatonin. But is there absolutely no way that someone could be put forcefully to sleep and still have a restful slumber?

Comment: Hypnotics and soporific drugs _are_ mild toxins, as seen in the movies when the despondent character takes and overdose of sleeping pills with the purpose of turning off the world. Basically there is no difference between a drug which put a person to sleep and one which "knocks them out" in a way which resembles sleep.

Comment: Also, when knocked out with sleeping pills, the sleep you get is generally not very good.

Comment: I don't think melatonin would work (see the symptoms of an overdose [here](http://www.healthline.com/health/melatonin-overdose#symptoms3)). It doesn't do a good job of helping you sleep normally, either ([see this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/1795/37236)).

Answer (score 2):

**Tiredness**

You can fight back the sudden need for sleep really easy if is not attached to fatigue or tiredness, you are conscious that your body is demanding that you close your eyes and lay over the floor, but a bump of sugar, adrenaline or will can dissipate the effect with ease.

If the effect needs to be immediate, then knock them out would be the best resource.

Comment: So there's no way that I can strengthen the effect?

Comment: @Calllack It's probable, as eating they are protective mechanism that evolve to keep us alive.But probably would demand a more direct interaction with the brain.